# Can sites built with Polymer work without JavaScript?

Tags: polymer

Can sites built with Polymer work without JavaScript? Seems like a standard question but I cant find an answer after some googling.

As its a browser polyfill I would assume its JavaScript reliance and its not the sort of thing that will degrade gracefully. But can this be fixed with server side rendering in some fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Just googling a couple of minutes:

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library))

> Polymer is an open-source **JavaScript library** for building web
>   applications using Web Components.

About the server side rendering there are some discussions [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3955)

Answer (score 0):

No, Polymer is written in JavaScript.

Comment: As is React but you can server side render and it's works without JavaScript.